# calling javascript function within another function synchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call `handleTotalAmount` function from `handleQuantity` function synchronously. Please find my below code. From `handleQuantity` its triggering `this.handleTotalAmount()` function async but, i want this to be triggered synchronously ( after the execuation of `this.props.getQuantity(this.props.item.product_quantity)`). But its now working as expected.

Added `getQuantity` Ajax API call too. so, from `handleQauntity` function i want to trigger `this.handleTotalAmount()` function only after the `this.props.getQuantity(this.props.item.product_quantity);` execuation. But, it not happening. Its working as an async way.

```
getQuantity(item)
{
    ajax({
        url: 'api/getQuantity',
        method : 'GET',
        data: {
            data: JSON.stringify(item)
        }
    }, (data) => {
        if(data.error == null )
            {
                    //Something...  
            }
        else {
            alert(data.error);
            }

    });
}

handleTotalAmount()
{
    this.props.totalAmountChange();
}

handleQuantity(e){
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(charCode === 13 || charCode === 9)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.props.getQuantity(this.props.item.product_quantity);
        }
    this.handleTotalAmount();
}
```

Comment: We'd need to see more of your code. The call to `this.handleTotalAmount()` in `handleQuantity` above is definitely synchronous. `handleQuantity` would appear to be an event handler, so it will be synchronous when that event handler is called, but...

Comment: If getQuantity is an async function then you could probably make use of async-await. like `async handleQuantity(e){
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(charCode === 13 || charCode === 9)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            await this.props.getQuantity(this.props.item.product_quantity);
            this.handleTotalAmount();
        }
}` or make use of componentDidUpdate lifecycle method

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Added Ajax api call code of `this.props.getQuantity(this.props.item.product_quantity);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous. Nothing in your code attempts to ensure that `handleTotalAmount` is called when the ajax call completes (in fact, your code always calls it regardless of whether you did the ajax call at all).

I'd probably address it with a promise. It looks like your `ajax` function uses old-style callbacks, so we'll have to create our own promise:

```
getQuantity(item)
{
    // Return the promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ajax({
            url: 'api/getQuantity',
            method : 'GET',
            data: {
                data: JSON.stringify(item)
            }
        }, (data) => {
            if(data.error == null ) {
                // No error, resolve the promise
                resolve(data);
            }
            else {
                // Error, reject the promise
                reject(data.error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

(It might be a good idea to give yourself a reuseable `ajax` that *does* provide a promise rather than doing this as a one-off.)

Then change your event handler to use that promise:

```
handleQuantity(e){
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(charCode === 13 || charCode === 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.getQuantity(this.props.item.product_quantity)    // ***
            .then(() => this.handleTotalAmount())                   // ***
            .catch(error => {                                       // ***
                // Handle error appropriately                       // ***
            });                                                     // ***
    }
}
```

Comment: Its giving `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error am using .then like this `.then(this.handleTotalAmount()) `

Comment: @Karthikeyan: If you're getting that error, you haven't modified `getQuantity` as shown to return the promise. Also, that's not how you'd use `then`. (But my answer's code using `.then` was also wrong, fixed now: `.then(() => this.handleTotalAmount())`.)

Comment: I followed your code., but somehow am getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error. and also `this.handleTotalAmount()` function triggering before the Ajax calls ends.

Comment: @Karthikeyan: All due respect, the code above definitely will not have those issues.